Stability order of xylenes
M-xylene is the most thermodynamically stable amongst the three isomers due to hyperconjugation. Can we comment on the stability order of the other two forms as well? If yes, what would be the order and the reason for the corresponding order?
Edit: To clarify, I want to know the order of stability of all the three xylenes. Is ortho more stable than para or vice versa?

The answer to your question is well explained here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/89747/thermodynamic-stability-of-meta-xylene-over-ortho-and-para-isomers
